# How can I copy project libraries from one project into another one in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libraries

I have a list of Project libraries:

[image]

I can't find a way to export/copy the libraries into another project.

How can one do that?

Comment: It looks like your intellij project is based on a gradle project description. So there should be a **text** file that contains that information. I guess you could just copy over that file (and adapt it where needed)?!

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 try to find something similar to `build.gradle`

Comment: @Ruslan Found it and added it to the corresponding file. I tried running the build gradle, but still it doesn't seem to work. Do I have to do this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy all libraries from gradle project to another gradle project you just need to copy `dependencies` section from `build.gradle` file to `build.gradle` from another project. Usually your build file looks like:

```
...
repositories {
    mavenCentral()     // that's where the gradle gets all libraries for project
}

dependencies {  // it's the list of dependencies are used for your project
    implementation 'library1Name'
    implementation 'library2Name'
    ...
}
...
```

See more [**Gradle Declaring Dependencies**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)

Comment: I think this answer should get the OP a long way. No idea why someone would downvote it.

Comment: Didn't work out, so I found another way: I moved all libraries to the Global Libraries one by one. Then I opened up my other project and transferred the libraries from the  Global Libraries to the Libraries. In Modules I had to tick all the Gradle data and apply the changes. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle (or Maven) based projects, after IDE pulls dependencies which you configure in build.gradle (pom.xml) file it stores them in project configuration files on Project level. See [Libraries and Global Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/libraries-and-global-libraries.html) section of documentation.

You indeed may move Libraries to **Global Libraries** making them available in other your projects, which may not use Maven or Gradle for managing dependencies:
[image]